# Match every instance of regex in BASH

Tags: regex, bash

I'm wondering if it's possible to use `BASH` binary operator `=~` with `BASH_REMATCH` to only match every instance of a regular expression in a given string.

For example, I try to get every set of digits from a string:

```
string="something 123 45 bla bla some OTHER characters 6789"
[[ $string =~ [0-9]{1,4} ]] && echo ${BASH_REMATCH[0]}
```

I'd like `${BASH_REMATCH[0}` to be `123 45 6789`, but it only matches the first instance of regex `[0-9]{1,4}` giving me `123`.

Can I accomplish this using only `BASH`, without having to do something else a little convoluted?

The following type of solution is what I want to avoid:

```
string="something 123 45 bla bla some OTHER characters 6789"
regex="([0-9]{1,4})"
[[ $string =~ ${regex}.*${regex} ]]
read -a s <<< "${BASH_REMATCH[0]}"
d=()
for i in ${s[@]}; do
    if [[ $i =~ $regex ]]; then
        d+=($i)
    fi
done
echo "The match I want is ${d[@]}"
```

In `ruby` I could do:

`string.scan(/(\d{1,4})/)`

and it would match what I want.

Is there an easier workaround for `BASH`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`BASH_REMATCH` doesn't quite work the way you're expecting, i.e. spit out multiple matches without capturing those into groups.  You could modify your script to let a function handle it:

```sh
string="something 123 45 bla bla some OTHER ch4r4ct3rs 6789"
regex="\b([0-9]{1,4})\b"

foo() {
  while [[ $1 ]]
  do
    [[ $1 =~ $regex ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
    shift
  done
}

foo $string
```

Executing this would produce:

```
123
45
6789
```

---

Alternatively, you could use `grep`:

```sh
grep -oP "$regex" <<< "$string"
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Gnu Awk version 4, you could do:

```
string="something 123 45 bla bla some OTHER ch4r4ct3rs 6789"
gawk '/^[0-9]{1,4}$/' RS="[[:space:]]+" <<<"$string"
```

Output:

```
123
45
6789
```

(For earlier versions of `gawk` you may have to use the switch `--re-interval`)