# bash regex not working - works with online editors

Tags: regex, bash, sh

Regex works with online editors but not in a bash script. Tried couple different ways

```
#!/bin/bash

echo -n "Your string> "
read String

regex='(?<!NOT.)TEST_34_TEST'

if [[ "$String" =~ ^(\?\<\!NOT\.)TEST_34_TEST ]]; then
    echo Match
else
    echo Non-Match
fi


if [[ "$String" =~ $regex ]]; then
    echo Match
else
    echo Non-Match
fi
```

I want string matching TEST_34_TEST and that does have NOT prefixed to it

```
TEST_34_TEST,TEST_34_TEST,TEST_34_TEST -> should match all 3
TEST_34_TEST, NOT_TEST_34_TEST, TEST_34_TEST -> should match 2 values
NOT_TEST_34_TEST, TEST_34_TEST, TEST_34_TEST -> should match 2 values
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: there is no look around support in BASH regex

Comment: ok is there a way to achieve it?

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21161095/3776858

Comment: `bash` doesn't capture multiple occurrences of a single group anyway. You can match against `NOT_TEST_34_TEST`, and the *entire* string either matches or it doesn't.

Comment: That wouldn't solve the problem as it matches other strings with NOT_TEST_34_TEST ex: TEST, TEST would return true

Comment: @Ttj: You can use `gnu grep`

Answer (score 0):

You can use GNU `grep` if you only want to know the number of matches (and not do anything with them)

```
for s in "TEST_34_TEST,TEST_34_TEST,TEST_34_TEST" "TEST_34_TEST, NOT_TEST_34_TEST, TEST_34_TEST" "NOT_TEST_34_TEST, TEST_34_TEST, TEST_34_TEST"; do
    grep -noP '((?<!NOT.)TEST_34_TEST)' <<< "$s" | wc -l
done
```

and will print

```
3
2
2
```